# Rails Form Not Updating the Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is this the correct way of defining form, let me know if I need to provide any more details.

This is the UserPreference forms in new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :user_preference, url: user_preferences_path do |u|%>
     <p>
        <%= u.label :title %><br>
        <%= u.text_field :title %>
      </p>

      <p>
        <%= u.label :description %><br>
        <%= u.text_field :description %>
      </p>

      <p> <%= u.label :back_ground_color %><br>
        <select name="bgcolor" id="bgcolor">
            <option value="#FF3300">Orange</option>
            <option value="#00FF00">Green</option>
            <option value="#0000FF">Blue</option>
            <option value="#FF0066">Pink</option>
            <option value="#FFFF00">Yellow</option>
            <option value="#FFFFFF">White</option>
        </select>
      </p>

      <p>
        <%= u.label :font %><br>
        <select name="font" id="font">
            <option value="Times New Roman">Times new Roman</option>
            <option value="Verdana">Verdana</option>
            <option value="Arial">Arial</option>
            <option value="sans-serif">serif</option>
        </select>
      </p>

     <br >
      <p>
        <%= u.submit %>
      </p>
```

I am getting title and description when I am trying to render in html,
the attribute is not getting updated in database.

**UserPreference.controller.rb**

```
class UserPreferencesController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @user_preference = UserPreference.new
    end

    def create
        @user_preference = UserPreference.new(userp_params)
        @user_preference.save unless user_signed_in?
        render plain: params[:user_preference].inspect
    end
    def edit
    end
    def update
    end

    private
    def userp_params
        params.require(:user_preference).permit(:title, :bgcolor, :font, :description)
    end
end
```

Comment: No it is still not updating in params, whether I am missing anything in giving the options value in forms

Comment: People are busy in voting down for this question but they can't answer the problem

Comment: check you're getting all the params in controller

Comment: @user120 I can see all the values getting updated in my rails console but when I am trying to render this in controller as plain hash it is showing just title and description, I am unable to update the database as well

Comment: might be this a guess, can you change that two options into rails specific tags

Comment: @user120 I changed it still the same

Comment: @cyborg You are getting downvotes because your question appears to be "is this how you define a form". You only actually sneak in the real problem halfway down the question. You need to make your actual problem more prominent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say this

```
<%= u.text_field :description %>
```

because you are working with :user_preference, it will make an input like

```
<input type="text" name="user_preference[description]" value="foo">
```

(where 'foo' is the current value, or maybe it's blank)

Note the "name" attribute:  this will go into params like

```
params = {:user_preference => {:description => "foo"}}
```

If you are going to hand-code the select then you need to make sure the name attribute has this structure too, eg

```
 <select name="user_preference[bgcolor]" id="bgcolor">
```

So you will get params like

```
params = {:user_preference => {:description => "foo", :bgcolor => "#FFFFFF"}}
```

Which then allows you to say

```
@user_preference.attributes = params[:user_preference]
```

which is the standard way to deal with this in the controller.

However, rather than writing out all the html for the select, it's much nicer to use the rails form helpers (`select` in this case) like you do with the text fields.  You can also define the options for the select with the `options_for_select` helper, which saves a lot of typing too.

```
 <%= u.select :bgcolor, options_for_select([["Orange", "#FF3300"], ["Green", "#00FF00"], ["Blue", "#0000FF"], ["Pink", "#FF0066"], ["Yellow", "#FFFF00"], ["White", "#FFFFFF"]]) %>
```

It's also cleaner to define this variable of options in your code somewhere, eg in a UserPreference class method:

```
class UserPreference < ActiveRecord::Base

  #class methods section
  class << self

    def bgcolor_options
      [["Orange", "#FF3300"], ["Green", "#00FF00"], ["Blue", "#0000FF"], ["Pink", "#FF0066"], ["Yellow", "#FFFF00"], ["White", "#FFFFFF"]]
    end
  end
end
```

Now you can use the select like so:

```
 <%= u.select :bgcolor, options_for_select(UserPreference.bgcolor_options) %>
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#the-select-and-option-tags

Comment: Could you please add equal to sign in form tag in last line.  <%= u.select :bgcolor, options_for_select(UserPreference.bgcolor_options) %>